# vba using win32 api, showwindow function closes window

Tags: vba, winapi

```
#If VBA7 And Win64 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function PostMessage Lib "user32" Alias "PostMessageA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, lParam As Any) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetClassName Lib "user32" Alias "GetClassNameA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal nMaxCount As Long) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function ShowWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal nCmdShow As Long) As Long
#End If

Private Sub close_window()

Dim WinWnd As Long, Ret As String, RetVal As Long, lpClassName As String
'Ask for a Window title
'Ret = InputBox("Enter the exact window title:" + Chr$(13) + Chr$(10) + "Note: must be an exact match")
'Search the window
WinWnd = FindWindow(vbNullString, "somedocument.docx - Word")
If WinWnd = 0 Then MsgBox "Couldn't find the window ...": Exit Sub
'Show the window
ShowWindow WinWnd, SW_SHOWNORMAL
'Create a buffer
lpClassName = Space(256)
'retrieve the class name
RetVal = GetClassName(WinWnd, lpClassName, 256)

'Show the classname
MsgBox "Classname: " + Left$(lpClassName, RetVal)
'Post a message to the window to close itself

'PostMessage WinWnd, WM_CLOSE, 0&, 0&
End Sub
```

The purpose of the aforementioned code is to close a Word document. But, even if comment the `PostMessage WinWnd, WM_CLOSE, 0&, 0&`
as showed above, the word doc indeed closes whereas uncommenting the postmessage command, the window doesn't close. I have come to the conclusion (by commenting line by line the above code) that ShowWindow WinWnd, SW_SHOWNORMAL function closes the window(word document). Is this normal?

Comment: Word exposes an [object model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/overview/word/object-model) so you don't have to fiddle with window handles to interact with it.

Comment: `FindWindow` API should return a `LongPtr`. So your function declaration is not correct. Then, do you want playing with API functions, or you really want quitting Word in this way? If you do not want experimenting some API calls, there are other more appropriate ways to do that. I can show you, if this is what you really want.

Comment: FaneDuru I've changed the declaration of functions and variables accordingly and now it works like a charm! Thank you all so much!

Comment: OK. Glad I could help, but you did not answer my question related to what you want. Playing with API can be something nice and good for learning, but this is what you want?

Comment: FaneDuru It was mainly for learning!

Comment: You need to start using `Option Explicit` at the beginning of each module. `SW_SHOWNORMAL` and `WM_CLOSE` are not constants that VBA recognizes. You need to assign them the appropriate values e.g. see [ShowWindow function (winuser.h)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-showwindow). If you want to hide the window you would use e.g. `Const SW_HIDESHOW As Long = 0` at the beginning of the procedure and use `SW_HIDESHOW` instead of `SW_SHOWNORMAL`.

Answer (score 2):

Following FaneDuru's suggestions here is the code that succesfully accomplishes the task:

```
#If VBA7 And Win64 Then
Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function PostMessage Lib "user32" Alias "PostMessageA" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, lParam As Any) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetClassName Lib "user32" Alias "GetClassNameA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal nMaxCount As Long) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function ShowWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal nCmdShow As Long) As Long

#End If

Private Sub Form_Load()

Dim WinWnd As LongPtr, Ret As String, RetVal As Long, lpClassName As String
'Ask for a Window title
'Ret = InputBox("Enter the exact window title:" + Chr$(13) + Chr$(10) + "Note: must be an exact match")
'Search the window
 WinWnd = FindWindow(vbNullString, "some_document.docx - Word")
 If WinWnd = 0 Then MsgBox "Couldn't find the window ...": Exit Sub
 'Show the window
 ShowWindow WinWnd, SW_SHOWNORMAL
 'Create a buffer
 lpClassName = Space(256)
 'retrieve the class name
 'RetVal = GetClassName(WinWnd, lpClassName, 256)

 'Show the classname
 'MsgBox "Classname: " + Left$(lpClassName, RetVal)
 'Post a message to the window to close itself

 PostMessage WinWnd, WM_CLOSE, 0&, 0&
 End Sub
```